# I can't display complete a table made with ltablex

Tags: koma-script, tabularx, ltablex

As you have seen in my last questions recently asked here, I'm working with tables.

Usually with `tabularx` is enough for me to satisfy the needs that I have with my tables. But one of them, even when I put it in two columns, that is, as the table only has 2 columns, I duplicated the to occupy better the width of the page, it still doesn't fit on one page.

I saw that there is a package that combines `longtable` with `tabularx` called `ltablex` and could then solve my problem. I checked the *manual* (sic) in the CTAN and tried to understand how it works. Since I have no information on the footer, I omitted the creation of it and I tried to create the header following the logic of the package but I can't make the table display complete in the page.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=letter,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true,titlepage=on]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[
 ItalicFont = SourceSerifPro,
 ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2}
 ]{SourceSerifPro} 
\setsansfont{SourceSansPro} 
\setmonofont{SourceCodePro}
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,multicol,rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,ltablex} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}    
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\setcellgapes{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Empresas Interesadas en la Explotación de los hidrocarburos de México}
\label{tab:interesadas}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Y l Y l @{}}
\toprule
Nombre & País de Origen & Nombre & País de Origen \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
Nombre & País de Origen & Nombre & País de Origen \\
\midrule
\endhead

%Nothing in footer

Atlantic Rim México, S. DE R.L. DE C.V. & Estados Unidos & Marathon Offshore Investment Limited & Estados Unidos \\
BG Group Mexico Exploration, S.A. de C.V. & Inglaterra & Mitsubishi Corporation & Japón \\ 
BHP Billiton Petróleo Operaciones de México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Australia-Inglaterra & Murphy Worldwide, Inc. & Estados Unidos \\
BP Exploration México, S.A. de C.V. & Gran Bretaña & NBL Mexico Inc. & Estados Unidos \\
Casa Exploration, L.P. & Estados Unidos & Nexen Energy Holdings International Limited & China \\
Chevron Energía de México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Estados Unidos & ONGC Videsh Limited & India \\
Cobalt Energía de México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Estados Unidos & Pan American energy LLC. & Argentina \\
Compañía Española de Petróleo, S.A. (CEPSA) & España & Pacific Rubiales E\&P México S.A.P.I. DE C.V. & Colombia \\
Diavaz Offshore, S.A.P.I. de C.V. & México & Petrobal S.A.P.I. de C.V. & México \\
E\&P Hidrocarburos Y Servicios, S.A. de C.V. & Argentina & Petróleo Brasileiro México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Brasil \\
Ecopetrol, S.A. & Colombia & Petronas Carigali International E\&P B.V. & Malasia \\
Eni International B.V. & Italia & Plains Acquisition Corporation & Estados Unidos \\
Exxon Mobil, S.A. & Estados Unidos & Pluspetrol México B.V. & Argentina \\
Galp Energia E\&P B.V. & Portugal & Premier Oil PLC & Inglaterra \\
Glencore E\&P Mexico LTD. & Suiza & PTT Exploration and Production Public Company Limited & Tailandia \\
Hess New Ventures Limited & Estados Unidos & Shell Exploración y Extracción de México, S.A. de C.V. & Inglaterra-Holanda \\
Hunt Overseas Oil Company & Estados Unidos & Sierra Oil \& Gas, S. de R.L. de C.V. & México \\
Inpex Corporation & Japón & Statoil E\&P México, S.A. de C.V. & Noruega \\
Japan Oil, Gas and Metals National Corporation & Japón & Talos Energy LLC & Estados Unidos \\
Japan Petroleum Exploration Co., Ltd. & Japón & Total, S.A. & Francia \\
Lukoil Overseas Netherlands B.V. & Rusia & Tullow México B.V. & Inglaterra \\
M{\ae}rsk Olie OG GAS A/S & Dinamarca & Woodside Energy Mediterranean Pty LTD & Australia \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I don't know what's wrong with this. Should I include a footer? Should I include `\keepXColumns` or `\convertXColumns`? What are they for? How do they work?

Comment: At first you shouldn't use the table environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third page of the table (to show referencing):

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=letter,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true,titlepage=on]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[
 ItalicFont = SourceSerifPro,
 ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2}
 ]{SourceSerifPro} 
\setsansfont{SourceSansPro} 
\setmonofont{SourceCodePro}
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,multicol,rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,ltablex} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}    
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\setcellgapes{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

{%
\captionof{table}{Empresas Interesadas en la Explotación de los hidrocarburos de México}
\label{tab:interesadas}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Y l Y l @{}}
\toprule
Nombre & País de Origen & Nombre & País de Origen \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
Nombre & País de Origen & Nombre & País de Origen \\
\midrule
\endhead

%Nothing in footer

Atlantic Rim México, S. DE R.L. DE C.V. & Estados Unidos & Marathon Offshore Investment Limited & Estados Unidos \\
BG Group Mexico Exploration, S.A. de C.V. & Inglaterra & Mitsubishi Corporation & Japón \\ 
BHP Billiton Petróleo Operaciones de México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Australia-Inglaterra & Murphy Worldwide, Inc. & Estados Unidos \\
BP Exploration México, S.A. de C.V. & Gran Bretaña & NBL Mexico Inc. & Estados Unidos \\
Casa Exploration, L.P. & Estados Unidos & Nexen Energy Holdings International Limited & China \\
Chevron Energía de México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Estados Unidos & ONGC Videsh Limited & India \\
Cobalt Energía de México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Estados Unidos & Pan American energy LLC. & Argentina \\
Compañía Española de Petróleo, S.A. (CEPSA) & España & Pacific Rubiales E\&P México S.A.P.I. DE C.V. & Colombia \\
Diavaz Offshore, S.A.P.I. de C.V. & México & Petrobal S.A.P.I. de C.V. & México \\
E\&P Hidrocarburos Y Servicios, S.A. de C.V. & Argentina & Petróleo Brasileiro México, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Brasil \\
Ecopetrol, S.A. & Colombia & Petronas Carigali International E\&P B.V. & Malasia \\
Eni International B.V. & Italia & Plains Acquisition Corporation & Estados Unidos \\
Exxon Mobil, S.A. & Estados Unidos & Pluspetrol México B.V. & Argentina \\
Galp Energia E\&P B.V. & Portugal & Premier Oil PLC & Inglaterra \\
Glencore E\&P Mexico LTD. & Suiza & PTT Exploration and Production Public Company Limited & Tailandia \\
Hess New Ventures Limited & Estados Unidos & Shell Exploración y Extracción de México, S.A. de C.V. & Inglaterra-Holanda \\
Hunt Overseas Oil Company & Estados Unidos & Sierra Oil \& Gas, S. de R.L. de C.V. & México \\
Inpex Corporation & Japón & Statoil E\&P México, S.A. de C.V. & Noruega \\
Japan Oil, Gas and Metals National Corporation & Japón & Talos Energy LLC & Estados Unidos \\
Japan Petroleum Exploration Co., Ltd. & Japón & Total, S.A. & Francia \\
Lukoil Overseas Netherlands B.V. & Rusia & Tullow México B.V. & Inglaterra \\
M{\ae}rsk Olie OG GAS A/S & Dinamarca & Woodside Energy Mediterranean Pty LTD & Australia \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}%
Table \ref{tab:interesadas} shows ...
\end{document}
```

First, as suggested by @UlrikeFischer, you should get rid of the `table` environment because, as the documentation says:

> The file modifies the `tabularx` environment to combine the features of the `tabularx` package (auto-sized columns in a fixed width table) with those of the `longtable` package (multi-page tables).

So, you needn't add `table`. For referencing just use the `\captionof` command with adding your label. It is better to add two braces `{}` around the table to prevent `\captionof` errors.

Comment: Great! it works. Now a silly question: There is a very long time I see code samples where at the end of a line people add a `%` symbol, no matters if there is a comment following that symbol or not. Now in your answer, you and a pair of `%` also after the braces you suggest me include (that worked BTW). So my question is why people do that? It has an special meaning or a reason for that?